# Reading a line from a text file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read a line from a text file, but the program keeps returning an error stating that the file's name cannot be located. Any ideas on how to solve the problem.

Source code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Cipher {

    public String file_name;

    public Cipher(){
        file_name = "/Users/SubrataMohanty/IdeaProjects/CaesarCipher/src/cipher_text.txt";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        Cipher cipher_1 = new Cipher();


        fr = new FileReader(cipher_1.file_name);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String current_line;

        while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(current_line);
        }

        }

    }
```

Upon debugging this is what I get,

```
Error:(25, 14) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Error:(30, 43) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

The above two lines are where :

1. Variable fr is initialized.
2. The while loop.

Comment: pls set the complete path to the file

Comment: Please enter the exact location where the file is there like c:/Users/.... . This will fix your issue.

Comment: @MMonisAhmedKhan I have set the complete path, haven't I?

Comment: I am using Mac with Intellij IDE as the editor.

Comment: Put the initialization of those variables in a try-catch block, after you read about what this block does and about exceptions in java. The error messages are usually all you need to get going. In this case, just googling them, I am sure, would give you the right answer.

Comment: Also, it's better if you don't access the fields of a class directly, but instead, you should use getters and setters to do that (e.g., create a method `public String getFileName() { return fileName;}` and call it from the main method, instead of directly accessing the `fileName` field. It would be also nice if you used a parameter in the constructor to set this field.

Comment: Change your main method declaration from `public static void main(String[] args) {` to `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{`. ie Declare the exceptions can be thrown as your javac error is telling you.

Comment: Don't forget to close your readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting these errors because the methods and constructors you are calling throw exceptions. These either need to be caught with a try/catch block or be declared in the method signature.

These errors are *compile time* errors, not runtime. It's not saying that the file doesn't exist, but that you need to catch an exception just in case that is true.

[Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Thank you very much. As a beginner I am on the look out for documentations more than code.

Answer (score 0):

Please Enter the complete path that is the Drive along with the folder location.

```
C:\....\Users/SubrataMohanty/IdeaProjects/CaesarCipher/src/cipher_text.txt
```

Like this. It should be like when you copy paste in the explorer you can jump to the file directly.

If using MAC then, right click on the text file and properties and copy the location and paste it in your code.

Comment: That is exactly how I typed in the path for file_name.

Comment: Did you copy the path from the properties and enter it to your code ?

Comment: Well in the editor I use, I have cipher_text.txt in my src folder. Right clicking on the text file helps me obtain the path which I then copy pasted to my code. I am using Intellij as my IDE.

Comment: You've completely missed the point, OP is not even able to compile their code.

Comment: @matt In his defense, OP never mentioned anything about compiling or javac.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, below lines need to catch

```
  fr = new FileReader(cipher_1.file_name);
  br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Use try-catch block or throws Exception to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{  
        fr = new FileReader(cipher_1.file_name);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String current_line;

        while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(current_line);
}catch(Exception e)
        e.printStackTrace();
{
```

You need to handle the exceptions generated by your reader

Answer (score 0):

Your file path should include the entire path for example:

```
"C:\\Users\\John Doe\\Desktop\\Impactor_0.9.41.txt"
```

Notice I used an extra '\' but I'm not sure if that matters, however I always do that.

Also for clarity you could also change your br and fr like this, however what you did is fine as well. But it is important to do the opening of files in a try-catch block like this:

```
try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cipher1.file_name));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also when reading and printing out file to console, put it in try catch:

```
try{
    String current_line;
    while((current_line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(current_line);
        current_line = br.readLine();
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The extra `\ ` is for escaping the following `\ `. Though using `/` is also acceptable for File regardless of OS.